# Can I use the same library in VB6 as a component and a reference?

Tags: vb6

I would like to use the Winsock Comm control. Some forms have used it as a control on the form (component) but I also have some classes which have references and created a new MSComm object.

This seems to fail with VB6. You can either add it as a component or reference. Is there any way to do both in the same project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mktyplib.exe` to compile a custom "direct controls" typelib like this

```
[
  uuid(<<GUID_HERE>>),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("Direct Controls Typelib 1.0")
]
library DirectControls10
{
    importlib("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mscomm32.ocx");

    typedef [public] MSCommlib.MSComm DirectMSComm;
}
```

Once you reference `DirectControls10` in your project you can use `DirectMSComm` coclass along `MSCommlib.MSComm` usercontrol like this

```
Private WithEvents m_oComm      As DirectMSComm

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set m_oComm = New DirectMSComm
    Set m_oComm = CreateObject("MSCommlib.MSComm")
    Set m_oComm = MSComm1.Object
End Sub

Private Sub m_oComm_OnComm()
    Debug.Print "m_oComm_OnComm"; Timer
End Sub
```

... where in the sample above `MSComm1` is a "comm control" on `Form1`.

You **don't** have to distribute this custom `.tlb` file to you clients. Use it on your dev machines only.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a component reference is a special kind of reference.  So once you have referenced a component, you can access it as a referenced library.

Comment: Yes, but if I add it as a component, then I cannot create a new object from class

Set comm = new MComm ' doesnt work

I can only use the visual component on the form. And if I only add a reference, then I can create new ones, but the ones that used to be on the forms get converted to PictureBox-es...

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Winsock *or* MSComm?

If its the latter, remove the component from the forms then remove it as a component in the tool box.

Add it as a reference and in the forms where previously there were components declare the instance manually;

```
private withevents comm as MSComm
```

creating them in `_load`

```
set comm = new MSComm
```

and all your events should be wired up so long as the variable name is the same.

If its a Winsock component then the simplest way is to use the OCX component & pass a reference from the form to the class as necessary, as you cannot reliably early bind a winsock component; `set wsck1 = new winsock` will compile & run fine but on any machine without VB6 installed it will fail as the winsock component does a license validation everytime one is created in that fashion.

I am 90% sure this isnt the case for mscomm but best to test anyway.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is pretty much what I've done. I was just hoping I didn't have to do this manually everywhere since it's a big project. I was kinda hoping I could use them together seamlessly.

Ah I missed the previous post. Seems like it can be done by creating a custom tlb! Awesome!

Answer (score -2):

A UserControl is a specialized form of Class anyway, so to wrap a control you create a UserControl.  You can easily make a non-UI UserControl invisible at runtime via the clearly named InvisibleAtRuntime property.

Comment: My question is about components and references being used together, not about usercontrols.

Comment: And my answer was to not use a Class as a control wrapper.  This is what we have UserControls for.